# QT arguments, equivalent of CONFIG+= in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5

I'm converting my qmake project to cmake.

In my pro file y have building directives like:

```
abc {
  INCLUDEPATH += 
  DEFINES +=
  HEADERS += 
  SOURCES +=
}
```

To use this building directive I use "CONFIG+=abc" in: project -> build -> build steps -> additional arguments.

In cmake I have defined

```
if(abc){
}
```

But I don't have how to use it to do the build with cmake.
I have try to do a custom process step during the building adding "--abc" but it doesn't work, and I don't know if I'm missing a key word as it is CONFIG+= in qmake

Answer (score 0):

Someone explain it to me:

It has to be defined

```
set(abc OFF CACHE BOOL "")
```

Now "abc" is a boolean set to false.

In QT->Projects->Cmake in Key column will appear the variable "abc" and we can change its value from here